# System.ArgumentException thrown with pictureBox

Tags: c#, exception

I have a WinForm application being developed with two forms, `PME` and `perfilAcesso`. I recently created `perfilAcesso` so that `PME` calls `perfilAcesso` when it starts. To do so, I wrote:

```
public partial class PME : Form
{
    perfilAcesso perfilAcesso = new perfilAcesso();
    PME pme = new PME();

    public PME()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        perfilAcesso.Show();
        pme.Hide();
    }
}
```

I first ran it without `pme.Hide();`, and later realized I wanted to hide `PME` while `perfilAcesso` is shown, so I added the line and ran it again. Then, it gave me this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

at this line of `Form2.Designer.cs`:

```
 this.pictureBox5.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox5.Image")));
```

I did some research, but it wasn't very helpful, as most of the links involved this exception happening with Bitmap classes. I also tried changing the image loaded in the `pictureBox5`, but nothing changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `PME pme = new PME();` Doesn't that cause infinite recursion?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks! It solved the problem, which had nothing to do with the pictureBox actually. But if infinite recursion is the problem here, shouldn't the exception be `System.OutOfMemory` instead?

Comment: It could be related to this note on MSDN: _If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur._ And also this _GetObject method can return a reference to an existing resource object in a cache, or it can reload the resource and return a reference to a new resource object._

Comment: OK. So, let's say every time I created a carrot the first thing it did was create a new carrot. You'd thus keep creating an unlimited supply of carrots! Now, let's go back to your code. Why did you add `PME pme = new PME();` there? What problem were you trying to solve with that line of code?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra But because of the recursion, `perfilAcesso perfilAcesso = new perfilAcesso();` creates many (more than 1) of the 2nd form, each with a `pictureBox5` object and each one calls `GetObject()`.

Comment: First of all, great analogy! Now, I added `PME pme = new PME();` there so I could have a reference to Form2, which was renamed to PME (and the reason why I wanted to access it, is so that when Form1 - `perfilAcesso` starts, it immediately calls `PME`, and is hidden after.

Comment: But you already have a reference to a `PME`. Itself! You can just use `this`. Your carrot doesn't need another carrot - it **is** a carrot!

Comment: Thanks guys! All your help was very valuable, and helped me solve the problem and improve my knowledge. Thanks for being patient and polite!